# golang fails to parse json for reflection created object

Tags: json, reflection, go, unmarshalling

I try to write simple message protocol in go and i've encountered a problem. I have a lot of message types and i want to have a dictionary like this to manipulate with messages:

```
var dict map[reflect.Type]int = map[reflect.Type]int{
    reflect.TypeOf(DataMessage{}):          1000,
    reflect.TypeOf(TextMessage{}):          1001,
    //....
}

func GetMessageTypeId(value interface{}) int {
    if id, ok := dict[reflect.TypeOf(value)]; ok {
        return id
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}

func GetValueByTypeId(typeId int) interface{} {
    for typeDec, id := range dict {
        if id == typeId {
            return reflect.Zero(typeDec).Interface()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Unknown message type", typeId)
    return nil
}
```

It works fine, but when i instantiate message with GetValueByTypeId and try to unmarshall json into it - i receive map[string]interface instead of my message.
I've made simple example to reproduce the problem:

http://play.golang.org/p/QEyDN9vztr

Comment: In your example you're using `reflect.Zero` and not `reflect.New` for destination3. changing to `New` solves the problem. But in your question it's `New`, so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: I remade example with `New` but the result is just the same http://play.golang.org/p/Ts0jvApwtY

Comment: I didn't mentioned that 
`val := reflection.New(type).Interface(); json.Unmarshal(data, val)` works, but i need not the pointer, but the value itself. And in this case i can't do conversion `return *val` - because of error `invalid indirect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this article: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces, especially the "Memory Optimizations".

The interface{} by definition consists of two pointers - to method table (e.g. type) and to data it holds. So for

```
var destination3 interface{} = reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(Message{})).Interface()
```

it is empty method table (as `interface{}` has no methods) and reference to `Message{}`. Taking reference from it returns the reference to this struct so the unmarhal overwrites it with whatever matches `interface{}`.

If the data `interface{}` variable holds is a pointer itself, then it is optimized in a way that this pointer is used instead creating `interface{}` structure. So getting reference to it gives the reference to original variable.

http://play.golang.org/p/KsIS29rUAX

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var m1 struct{ Data string }
    var m2 interface{}
    var m3 interface{}

    m2 = &m1
    m3 = m1

    fmt.Printf("&m1=%p m2=%p &m3=%p\n", &m1, m2, &m3)
}
```

In your case, using Zero is equivalent to m3 in the example above. Using New is equivalent to m2.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comment explaines the problem heart and the article is very useful - unfortunately i didn't saw it before!

Comment: И спасибо вам по-русски :) Я догадывался, что примерно в эту сторону стоит копать, но до конца не дошёл. Я на го пишу не так давно и стараюсь вкапываться во все детали, а не писать лишь бы заработало. А статья, которую вы скинула - действительно очень интересная. К сожалению далеко не все подобные материалы по go лежат на поверхности - сам бы я вряд ли когда её нашёл...

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :) Задавайте вопросы - будем помогать, чем сможем.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way how to do what i need

```
val := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(Message{}))
json.Unmarshal(data, val.Interface())

return val.Elem().Interface()
```

http://play.golang.org/p/8g9FSg3MSj

But was was wrong wit the first version??? 
It Looks like `reflect.Zero(type)` should be equivalent to `reflect.New(type).Elem()` - am i wrong?